# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration - Android maven

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

When using Eclipse Juno, error says:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration

pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>14</platform>
                </sdk>
                <extractDuplicates>true</extractDuplicates>
                <emulator>
                    <avd>Android_2.2</avd>
                    <wait>45000</wait>
                    <options></options>
                </emulator>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install android-m2e connector.

You can install the Android Connector for Maven via the Eclipse Marketplace. Select Help -> Eclipse Marketplace... and search for "android m2e".

Credits: http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/